# Fix the 'background service' problem on Android 8+

Tags: java, android

I have code running a service behind the scenes. It is set to run when we copy the text to the phone.
This code works fine on Android 8 below
But the problem is when I run the app on Android 8 and above

In my searches, I realized that I had to use FOREGROUND_SERVICEs and give specific access to the project.

What solutions do you suggest now?

### **Service Class:**

```
public class AutoDownloadService extends Service {

    private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
       //  stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mClipboardManager != null) {
            mClipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }

    private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                    String textClipBoard = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(AutoDownloadService.this, textClipBoard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
}
```

### **Manifest**

```
<service
      android:name=".services.AutoDownloadService"
      android:exported="false"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

- and add finally uses permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: what is happening "**on Android 8 and above**" ?

Comment: @Maveňツ Doesn't work on Android +8

Comment: user intentService instead of service

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Does this intent service work on all versions of Android?

Comment: yup it will work just try it

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi  It worked great, but the point is that on Chinese phones or Chinese Rom the service will shut down when the program is closed from multitasking.

Comment: check answer accept and upvote it if you find it helpful

Comment: @Amirhf I try to reproduce your question using a project, but it seems that I do not totally understand your question. Could you create a project on Github and shows us the requirement you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use Intent Service instead of service.
what you can do is if system shutdown your service you can again trigger it after sometime using alarm manger.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in documentation

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both
>   foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the
>   background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still
>   allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app
>   is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's
>   background services, just as if the app had called the services'
>   Service.stopSelf() methods.

So, you solution is to run foreground service on Android >= 8.0 and do something like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(Intent(this, AutoDownloadService.class))
        } else {
            startService(Intent(this, AutoDownloadService.class))
        }
}
```

Comment: That's not my problem right now :(
 but the point is that on Chinese phones or Chinese Rom the service will shut down when the program is closed from multitasking

Comment: My question is `startForegroundService` work above 25 API level. But, how `WhatsApp`, `Facebook` and `Instagram` use it in every API level?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not do this.
Monitoring clipboard in background is not something right.

Android 8 added some protection on this, so **you should run as foreground services**, to let the end user aware your app is monitoring the clipboard.

Anyway clipboard access only available to default IME from Android 10. So, your apps will not work in Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

This example of my code is currently working fine but I have problems with Chinese mobile

**Tested on mobile: Xiaomi 7**

```
public class AutoDownloadService extends IntentService {

    private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;
    public AutoDownloadService() {
        super("AutoDownloadService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " service started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private final ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                    String textClipBoard = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                    if (textClipBoard.startsWith("https://www.instagram.com/")) {
                        Toast.makeText(AutoDownloadService.this, textClipBoard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
}
```

And in the file **Manifast.xml** This is how it is defined

```
 <service android:name="com.amirhf.inatasave.services.AutoDownloadService" />
```

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Please look at this piece of code and say what is the problem with not working on some Chinese mobile?

Comment: try debugging this maybe those Chinese phone does not support ClipboardManager .?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Chinese Phone => Yes I did a test when the application is open but it works properly when I close the application from multi-tasking.
But on other phones, the app works well, like Samsung, HTC and etc ...

Comment: share details of chinese phone?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Xiaomi redmi 7, Android version 9 | API level 28 | Build ID: PKQ1.18.1021.001

Comment: could you please explain if you kill the app. then what is happening on other phones?? and issue that you are facing on xiami redmi phone?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi When the application closes it will not show the toast.

Comment: try adding broadcast when ever you open instagram  trigger or restart your service.?

Comment: https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android have a look at this blog.

Answer (score 0):

When you swipe the app from recent apps, few Chinese OEMs force stop the apps.
Once the App is force stopped, you can't post notifications, start services, receive broadcasts etc.

> The only work around is : Your app should be whitelisted, added in
>   auto start list. Apps like WhatsApp, Facebook etc are already added by
>   the OEMs in the list.

This blog talks about similar problem of not receiving notifications when App is force stopped. https://hackernoon.com/notifications-in-android-are-horribly-broken-b8dbec63f48a

You can take a similar approach where you can have a "Troubleshoot" section where you can educate the user to add your app in auto start list.

> If by any chance your app is very popular you can get in touch with
>   Chinese Manufacturer and request them to get your app whitelisted but
>   they do it for very popular apps. For example in my experience
>   Microsoft and Hike Messenger got it done for their apps.

Comment: How does messaging like WhatsApp, Telegram, etc. work on all phones without issue? Even Chinese phones
Do we have to define specific access for each phone?

Comment: Like I mentioned above WhatsApp, Facebook, Messenger etc are already added to that whitelist automatically.  In addition to these apps there are other apps as well such as Hike Messenger, Microsoft Teams etc, they got in touch with these Chinese Manufacturer and got themselves added to the whitelist as these apps are  very much used.

Comment: As Arpit Ratan stated it is true, it would seem that they banned android store in 2017 so you need to contact all of their semi-android-app-store distributors in order to whitelist your app. Check here https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-develop-a-successful-app-for-chinese-market-2c5e80414198

Comment: It would appear that they went really above and beyond with this one... funny world this is... https://www.saporedicina.com/english/apps-blocked-china-access/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand if you're messing with file download or anything else. But I guess you're not going the right way. So here's what I may share.

From https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

> - If your app is performing long-running HTTP downloads, consider using    [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
> - If your app is synchronizing data from an external    server, consider creating a [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).
> - If your app relies on    background services, consider using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#js) or [Firebase Cloud    Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to trigger these services
>     at specific intervals.

Also note that if you just have a task that has to done often, use [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService). Its compatible with Oreo and versions below it:

> Helper for processing work that has been enqueued for a job/service.
>   When running on Android O or later, the work will be dispatched as a
>   job via **JobScheduler.enqueue**. When running on older versions of the
>   platform, it will use **Context.startService**.

On Oreo and above versions there are limitations helping the device save resources (battery, ram...) and even when using JobIntentService you must consider them; otherwise your app may be recognized as *Battery Draining App*.

If what you're about to do is heavy and is important enough to be shown in notification bar, do it using ForegroundService. So that it will be taken more seriously by android system and chances of it being killed gets fewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `WorkManager` it's a JetPack Library.

> Advantages:
>
> - Ensures task execution, even if the app or device restarts (**Guaranteed Execution**)
> - You don’t need to write device logic to figure out what capabilities the device has and choose an appropriate API; instead, you can just hand your task off to `WorkManager` and let it choose the best option. It is a wrapper on all the above concepts.
> - Uses `JobScheduler` on devices with **API 23+**
> - Uses a combination of `BroadcastReceiver` + `AlarmManager` on devices with **API 14-22**

[image: WorkManager Flow]

Ref : [WorkManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)
Ref : [Medium Article](https://medium.com/mindorks/lets-work-manager-do-background-processing-58356e1ab844)
Ref : [Medium Article(1)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-basics-beba51e94048)

[Update] - stable version is out [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.3.0)